# Loosing the scope in Ajax call sucess

Tags: javascript

I am writing on a service call in my method. Once ajax call is getting fire I am getting the response. But after getting the response I am losing the other variable of the method in ajax success,

Here is my code.

```
refreshClick: function(options) {
  let _this = this,
    selectedrecord = this.getView().getStore().getAt(options.rowIndex);
  let reqObj = {
    url: options.url + selectedrecord.data.val,
    method: 'get',
  };
  _this.getGridService().loadGridStoreData(reqObj).then({
    success: function(response) {
      debugger;
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', result);
      _this.getView().getStore().load();
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Now after getting success in debugger line, I am not getting the value of `options` or `selectedRecs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably the debugger removing unused variables from the scope, reference the variables inside the function:

```
console.log(options,selectedRecs);
debugger;
```

And you should be able to access its values.